# Динамическая подгрузка сообщений с XMPP-сервера

Tags: xmpp, objective-c, ios

Здравствуйте! Ситуация следующая. Я использую xmpp-сервер. Есть приложение-чат на телефоне/ Пользователь заходит в чат и тут же нужно подгрузить несколько последних сообщений. Как лучше это сделать? Если пользователь станет проматывать выше? то нжно подгрузить еще несколько предыдущих сообщений. Ну, я думаю, понятно что нужно. Так вот. Я нашел несколько способов. Первый это через выборку управляющих объектов, а второй черех iq-запросы. Но первый явно не подходит судя по некоторым статьям, а второй не хочет возвращать всю переписку. То есть ответ приходит только с сообщениями из первого листа диалога. Приложение под ios. Использую XMPPFraemwork и OpenFire